# How to make boxes occupy two columns in twocolumn environment, without using float in LaTeX?

Tags: sectioning, two-column, framed

I am trying to create a new document class, similar to books, but with two columns and where new chapters always starts in a new page, printing the chapter name inside a box that should occupy two columns. How to do something like this?

Comment: Note: using floats wouldn't work in this case, because I want the box in an specific position.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303637/how-to-make-boxes-occupy-two-columns-in-twocolumn-environment-without-using-flo?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `titlesec` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) provides a good interface for sectioning commands:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.}{1.0em}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-20pt}{10pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter Title}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. With some changes in this sample code I got the effect I was looking for. Thanks.